# Is the following reasoning right?

Tags: roots, common-root

I saw this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/comments/bqcrkn/you_can_find_the_answer_over_there_on_any_of_my/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) on Reddit and it had the following comment

> √x²=|x|
>   It's the principle square root solution. So the square root of 49 is 7. It's the definition of square root.
>   However the equation x²=7² has two solutions +7 & -7
>   Only because x²=7² --> x²-7²=0 --> (x+7)(x-7)=0 -->x= ±7
>   That's the difference between the two.
>   Here's an intuitive example to understand that:
>   y²=x is not the same as y=√x
>   On plotting the points the first equation will result in a complete parabola whereas, in the second equation it would make a half parabola because the function is defined in such a way.

Is this reasoning right? Because as far as I can remember we always wrote the value of a square root in ± form

Comment: I think $\sqrt *$ means the **arithmetic square root**, whereas $\pm \sqrt *$ are the **square roots**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify this: Take the equation $$y=x^2$$ for $y>0$. Then, this equation has two solutions, $y=\sqrt x$ and $y=-\sqrt x$. This is what you mean by "$\pm$ form".

The square root is defined as the non-negative solution of this equation. Simply because we want the square root to have specific properties (like that it becomes a function again), so we have to give the square root a unique value.

You can also think of it as the inverse function of the function $f(x)=x^2$. Because $f$ has to be bijective, we somehow have to restrict the domain; to get the same as above, we can choose $f:\mathbb R_{\geq0}\to\mathbb R_{\geq0}$. This also has the implication that the square root is only the non-negative solutuion of the equation above.

To sum this up, there is a difference between the square root (which is unique) and the solutions of quadratic equations (which do not have to be unique).

Answer (score 0):

I get why you're confused here. But the idea that $y^2 = x$ is not equivalent to saying $y =\sqrt x$ hits the nail.

$$y^2 = x$$

has two solutions, $\pm \sqrt x$ as squaring both quantities will give me $x$. The solution to this equation are called the "square roots".

Now when I look at say

$$y = \sqrt{x^2}$$.

then $y = |x|$ is the only solution, and this solution is called the "principal square root".

"But why?" you can ask. "If I have $y = \sqrt{49}$, I can write $49 = (-7)^2$ and $49=(7)^2$, right? So that means both $y=\pm 7$ satisfy the equation $y=\sqrt{49}$?" you can implore.

Good question!

Now you see the symbol $\sqrt .$ really means the principal square root, i.e. only the positive counterpart. It's in the definition of $\sqrt .$ that we only take the positive solution.

Comment: So to clarify, when I say $$sqrt{x^2} = 49$$ it will mean that $x=\pm7$ but if I say $$x = \sqrt49$$ it would mean that $x = +7$$.
Is this right?

Comment: $y^2 = x$ has two solutions, these are the two square roots of $x$. $y=\sqrt x$ has only one solution. It's called the principal square root of $x$.